# issue in stripe connected account to bank transfer

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

i have an issue in transfer.

my stripe connected account available bal is $200.00  and i have an transfer my $200.00  and pandding balance is $150.00 balance to my bank account.

to showing error  insuficient funds in your stripe connected account

see my code:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($_REQUEST['secret_id']);

$transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
    "amount" => 20000,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "destination" => "default_for_currency",
    "description" => $_REQUEST['description'],
    "source_type" => "bank_account"
));
```

see output :

```
{
    msg = "You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account for this transfer. Your ACH balance is too low.  You can use the the /v1/balance endpoint to view your Stripe balance (for more details, see stripe.com/docs/api#balance).";
    status = 0;
}
```

i need solution please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your account actually has more than one balance -- funds are split by payment source type.

If you send a [balance retrieval](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_balance) request, you will get a result similar to this:

```
{
  "available": [
    {
      "amount": 20000,
      "currency": "usd",
      "source_types": {
        "card": 12000,
        "bank_account": 8000
      }
    }
  ],
  "livemode": false,
  "object": "balance",
  "pending": [
    {
      "amount": 0,
      "currency": "usd",
      "source_types": {
        "card": 0,
        "bank_account": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When you [create a transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_transfer), you should specify the source type via the [`source_type`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_transfer-source_type) attribute. E.g. in PHP, you'd do something like this:

```
\Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
  "amount" => 8000,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "destination" => "default_for_currency",
  "source_type" => "bank_account"
));
```

On an unrelated note, it seems you're setting the API key via a client-side parameter:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($_REQUEST['secret_id']);
```

You should never share the secret API key with your client-side code. It would be very easy for an attacker to retrieve it and use it to issue API requests on your behalf. They'd be able to look at your transactions, delete saved customers, etc.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot :) 
Actually, I missed `"source_type" => "bank_account"`, so it looking into the card & says insufficient balance.

Answer (score 1):

When any charge is succeeded in stripe, it takes some time to actually available it in stripe account.

If You want to create the transfer based on any amount collected by any charge, then you can directly use the charge id. 
So your code should be like:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("your_secret_key");

$transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "source_transaction" => "{CHARGE_ID}",
  "destination" => "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}",
));
```

By using source_transaction, the transfer request succeeds regardless of your available balance and the transfer itself only occurs once the charge’s funds become available.

It is documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#transfer-availability)